# React js : Load font when want to print a component in a new tab

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, printing, font-face

I have written a component that prints the received data in a specific format. This component uses the printData method for printing. This method receives the component ID that needs to be printed, puts it in a new tab, and then prints it. The problem is that I have used a specific font throughout the program and defined the font face for it and put the font files in the project. But when this component opens in the new tab, it is not possible to load the font. Please guide me if you know a solution to this problem or if you have better solutions for this. Thankful.

```
export function printData(printDivId) {
  const mywindow = window.open("", "PRINT");

  mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(printDivId).innerHTML);

  mywindow.document.close();
  mywindow.focus();

  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close();

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I came to the conclusion that I should use the CDN link instead of the font file. This way, in the new window, I load the font via the link and add that style to the whole page. The printData method can be updated this way :

```
export function printData(printDivId) {
const mywindow = window.open("", "PRINT");
mywindow.document.write(
    '<html><head><style>@font-face {font-family: BYekan;src: url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/52ce4de2efeeb8b18dcbd379711224f3.eot");src: url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/52ce4de2efeeb8b18dcbd379711224f3.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/52ce4de2efeeb8b18dcbd379711224f3.woff2")format("woff2"),url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/52ce4de2efeeb8b18dcbd379711224f3.woff")format("woff"),url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/52ce4de2efeeb8b18dcbd379711224f3.ttf")format("truetype"),url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/52ce4de2efeeb8b18dcbd379711224f3.svg#B Yekan")format("svg");} body,html {font-family: BYekan !important;}</style></head><body>'
  );
  mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(printDivId).innerHTML);
  mywindow.document.write("</body></html>");
  mywindow.document.close();
  mywindow.focus();
  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close();
  return true;
}
```